# How to call Execute in class using Revit API in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, revit-api

I have a class containing functionality that works with Revit, I need to bind to a `Button` on a WPF form, an action that would launch a class that works with Revit. I am new to this, so I would like a detailed answer with a code example. I have already read many forums, but did not find the answer.

I tried referencing the class with

```
Class1 class1 = new Class1();
class1.Execute(commandData, ref sting, elements);
```

I was expecting the class I need to be called, but how did I find out that it is not possible to run a class using Revit API in a third-party application.

Comment: This question has been discussed and answered in the Revit API discussion forum thread on [How to call Execute in class using Revit API in WPF](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/revit-api-forum/how-to-call-execute-in-class-using-revitapi-in-wpf/m-p/11948549).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run Revit API in a third-party application, legally. The IExternalCommand.Execute method can only be called by Revit itself.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).